# InfoPath 2013 rich text box expand to show all text not working

Tags: infopath, rich-text

I have created a InfoPath 2013 form and I am having issues with rich text box not expanding automatically with "Expand to show all the text" setting is being set with wrap text. in the preview form it shows good but When I publish the form it shows the rich text fields with scroll bars. Strange thing is it works fine in other browsers except IE.Can some one really help me on this please., I can drop my form here to check what I am doing any wrong. Please find the screenshot of the rich text box properties.

[image: richtextboxissue]

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to the values you have on size (3rd Tab in the control properties), please change the height to 'Auto' if you have the numeric value there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed, In IE or Chrome the rich text box only works when the show the toolbar by default option is checked in at the form options. It helped me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by applying custom css on master page level:

```
textarea { white-space: pre-wrap !important; word-wrap: break-word !important; }
```

I am having column setup as Mukltiple line of text and Plain text.
Hope it helps.